# How to specify the Bayesian version of a clustered-robust standard error OLS in BUGS/JAGS or Stan?

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, jags, clustered-standard-errors, stan

I am trying to reproduce a simple OLS model fitted with clustered-robust standard errors within the Bayesian framework (be it with BUGS/JaGS or with Stan).

In R, my frequentist model is the following:

```
mymodel <- (lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + I(X1*X2), data = mydata));
```

In order to calculate the clustered-robust SE I use the following code:

```
clusteredSE <- function(fm, dfcw, cluster)
{
  library(sandwich)
  library(lmtest)
  library(zoo)
  M <- length(unique(cluster))
  N <- length(cluster)
  dfc <- (M / (M - 1)) * ((N - 1) / (N - fm$rank))
  u <- apply(estfun(fm), 2, function(x) tapply(x, cluster, sum))
  vcovCL <- dfc * sandwich(fm, meat = crossprod(u) / N) * dfcw
  coeftest(fm, vcovCL)
}

clusteredSE(mymodel, 1, mydata$countries)
```

Now, in either BUGS/JAGS or Stan, I understand how to specify both simple OLS models and also Hierarchical models. However, I did not understand nor find an example of how should I proceed for estimating what in the frequentist world would be a clustered-robust standard error OLS. Could any of you point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance for your time.

PS: I will be comparing that to hierarchical models, so yes, it would need to really be a Bayesian version of clustering the errors.

Comment: Is this a programming question or a statistics question?

Comment: @ssdecontrol It is certainly not a programming question. However, if what you mean is whether the question is about how to do something in the softwares or also about the theoretical implications behind it, I can confirm that I am interested in both, but even more in the second. So much so, that as the question specifies, I don't even care if that is done in BUGS, JAGS or Stan.

Comment: An answer that was given on [another forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/324eac20/?limit=25) was [ Szpiro, Rice and Lumley 2010 ](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/10-AOAS362). I am just reposting this here.